# Как изменить стиль псевдоэлемента при наведении на него курсора?

Tags: html, css, frontend, hover, псевдоэлемент

Крайне простая штука, которую никак не могу реализовать. Необходимо изменить цвет стрелки в слайдере (которая реализована как псевдоэлемент) при наведении на нее курсора.
Я делала так:

```
   .announcements:hover:before { 
    border-color:#474747;
}
```

Это работает, но цвет стрелки меняется не только при наведении на нее, но и при наведении на сам слайдер (annoucements), а этого я бы хотела избежать.

Подскажите, как реализовать данную задачу при помощи css или js?

*html-верстка слайдера*

```
<div class="poster">
<div class="announcements">
    <div class="announcements-item">
        <div class="announcements_date">26-27 <span>october</span> 2022</div>
        <div class="announcements_block">
            <div class="announcements_title">Wealth TOP FORUM Israel 2022</div>
            <div class="announcements_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
            <div class="announcements_location">Barcelona</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вёрстку (html) слайдера покажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавила верстку)

Comment: Обычно в слайдерах стрелки - это самостоятельные элементы управления. У Вас же они являются псевдоэлементами самого слайдера, поэтому реагируют на любое наведение на него. Более того, не очень понятно, как Ваш слайдер в принципе будет работать, потому что без "костылей" повесить клик на псевдоэлемент невозможно. Думаю, что Вам придётся корректировать вёрстку.

Comment: Поняла вас, значит переделаю верстку тогда, сделаю самостоятельными элементами. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Можно это сделать, вы вешаете событие наведения на сам слайдер, а надо на стрелочки

Comment: @QwertyQ, на псевдоэлементы отдельно от их родителя нельзя повесить никакие события

Comment: Ну тогда переверстать)